# crontab: run a command and kill its looped output after 2 min?

Tags: cron, kill

i want to run a command every 50 min and kill the looped output PID after 2 min of the command execution.

is this possible somehow? any help would be nice.

Answer (score 2):

Use "timeout" (man timeout for specifics). Setup a crontab to run your command but use`/usr/bin/timeout 120s your_command`

This should run your command for 120 seconds every time the crontab invokes it.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not experienced in using cron, but you can also just write a little Bash script that runs in background infinitely, like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
while true ; do         # starts an infinite loop
    YOUR_COMMAND &      # runs YOUR_COMMAND in background
    your_pid=$!         # remembers the PID of YOUR_COMMAND
    sleep 2m            # pauses the script for 2 minutes
    kill $your_pid      # kills YOUR_COMMAND by its previously remembered PID
    sleep 48m           # pauses the script for the remaining 48 minutes
done                    # defines the end of the loop
```

Comment: but when i already run the script there will be created a new PID,  is it possible to edit changed of script while its running.

Comment: I think I don't understand what you mean. The PID is unique for every instance of `YOUR_COMMAND` and changes on every iteration.